# How i can get the end event in javafx TextField

Tags: java, events, javafx, listener, textfield

I have a text field that receives a number read from barcode by scanner, but i don't know how many digits the barcode has, so, I would like to know when the event was finished, for get the complete number scanned.

Here is the code

```
txSerialId.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldText, newText) -> {
            
            System.out.println("addListener..........obs    : " + obs);
            System.out.println("addListener..........oldText: " + oldText);
            System.out.println("addListener..........newText: " + newText);
});
```

I am using JavaFx 8.

Comment: I don't know if this the answer you are looking for but the barcode consists of 12 digits

Comment: I think you can only do some heuristic approach to your issue. Like start a Timer when a first digit is entered and fire an TimerTask after the time that usually all digits have been entered. Similar to that you can measure time after last digit entered, it may be more precise.

Comment: @MarcinKrasowski A `TimerTask` will run in a background thread, which creates a lot of code complexity when interacting with a single-threaded UI toolkit like JavaFX. I would recommend using the animation API instead (see posted answer).

Comment: doesn't the scanner send something like eol? or a commit signal that you could catch by an action handler on the field?

Comment: The program can be installed in different machine and difference barcode and until qr code, I woldlike to do a generic, without a check the length.

Answer (score 1):

There's no particularly nice way to do this, as far as I know, because there's nothing that indicates the "end of scan" when reading this into a text field (unless you know ahead of time the length of the barcode text).

The best I can suggest is to wait until no changes have been input for some short period of time. This should work, because the text will be read by the scanner rapidly; it comes at the cost of a slight delay in reacting to the scan.

You can do this using a `PauseTransition`, and update a `StringProperty` when the pause completes:

```
final PauseTransition scannerDelay = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(0.25));
final StringProperty barcode = new SimpleStringProperty();
// when delay finishes, update barcode with text in text field:
scannerDelay.setOnFinished(event -> barcode.set(txSerialId.getText());
// when text in text field changes, start (or restart) the pause:
txSerialId.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldText, newText) -> 
    scannerDelay.playFromStart());

// react to changes in barcode:
barcode.addListener((obs, oldBarcode, newBarcode) -> 
    System.out.printf("Barcode changed from %s to %s %n", oldBarcode, newBarcode));
```

Comment: It is functioning to me James_D, no problem with the lost time, it is just any milliseconds.